# Blink when reloadData a UITableView with UIWebView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiwebview

Hi! I'm working with an UITableView, with UITableViewCell.
The UITableViewCell has inside an UIWebView (because i'm using entities, bold text, ecc...).

The webview is loaded with this code:

```
UIWebView *testoLabel2 = (UIWebView*)[cell viewWithTag:3];  
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><font size=2>%@</font></body></html>", sottotitolo];
testoLabel2.opaque = NO;
testoLabel2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 
[testoLabel2 loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

What's the problem?
That when i need to reload the data (for example after the change of the deviceOrientation) using

```
[my_table reloadData];
```

all the webView blink! 
For just a second, but they blink! And it's a very ugly effect!

Do you know why?
Thanks!

EDIT: also if i scroll down the tableview, when i scroll up the webview that before were loaded are white! But just for a moment, after they load the text!

Comment: that's because webViews loadHtmlString perform asynchronously. I'm having the same problem and the only solution I found was to use a richText that accepts html and replace the webView with that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly why but it's good practice to set all view backgrounds in cells to a solid solid color. The flash could be the cell rendering it's background and then the web view on top of it. If you set the webview background to your desired color and leave it opaque then this shouldn't happen. Good luck!

Comment: no, unfortunatley deleting `testoLabel2.opaque = NO;` and `testoLabel2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];` nothing change!

Comment: ok, that may not have solved your problem but it's still the right thing to do for table view performance.

Comment: another thought on this, you mentioned calling `reloadData` when the device orientation changes. You shouldn't need to do that. You should only reload data when the _data_ actually changes. If you are just loading the same content into the web view you are forcing the web view to load and render itself while the orientation animation is occurring.